# how can i add arguments for an exe in debugger?

Tags: debugging, arguments, exe, reverse-engineering

How do I add arguments to an exe that I want to debug in immunity debugger? I didn't find any option to add input or arguments. I can just run it with no parameters at all, and it's the wrong case for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When selecting the file to run from immunity, at the bottom of the dialog is a bar where you can specify arguments.

Additionally, you can launch the process manually, and attach immunity to it.